# Get partial view data on main view submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a Teachers class and Courses class. I am creating edit form for teachers where user can edit a teacher's information like name, title and courses that teacher is teaching. I have created a partial view to display courses information for a teacher. I have only one submit button in main edit view. When I submit the form and get the teachers object, its courses object is null though I have updated course field. Can please someone help me here?

```
public class TeacherTemplate
{
  public int teacherId { get; set;}
  public string TeacherName { get; set; }
  public string TeacherCourses { get; set; }
  public CourseTemplate Courses 
  {
        get => TeacherCourses == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CourseTemplate>(TeacherCourses);
        set => TeacherCourses = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Courses);
    }
}
public class CourseTemplate
{
  public string CourseName {get; set; }
  public int courseId { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public Subjects Subject { get; set;}
}
public class Subjects
{
  public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}
```

Main edit view for teachers

```
@model TeacherTemplate
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditTeacher";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModuleTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModuleTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

         @Html.Partial("_editCourse", Model)
        @*@Html.Action("EditCourse", "TeacherTemplate", new { teacherTemplate = Model })*@


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Courses Partial view

```
@model TeacherTemplate

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Courses.CourseName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Courses.CourseName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Courses.CourseName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Courses.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Courses.Active, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Courses.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="btnAddSubjects">Add Subject</button>
        if (Model.Courses.Subject.Count() > 0)
        {
            <div id="subjectContainer" class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Courses.Subject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Courses.Subject.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Courses.Subject[i].SubjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 80, @rows = 50 } })
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
         }
    </div>
}
```

TeacherTemplateController - Here when EditTeacher method is called on submit button from main view, teacherTemplate object has all teacher information bound correctly, but TeacherCourses property and Courses property/object both are null.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
public ActionResult EditTeacher(Guid teacherTemplateId)
            {
                var teacherTemplate= _teacherTemplateService.GetTeacherInfo(teacherTemplateId);
                return View(teacherTemplate);
            }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult EditTeacher(TeacherTemplate teacherTemplate)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var teacherTemplate1 = _teacherTemplateService.UpdateTeacherInfo(teacherTemplate);
return RedirectToAction("EditTeacher", new { teacherTemplateId = teacherTemplate.teacherTemplateId });

            }
            public ActionResult EditCourse(TeacherTemplate teacherTemplate)
            {
                return PartialView("_editCourse", teacherTemplate);
            }
```

Comment: Seems like you’re using ‘teacherTemplate’ instead of ‘moduleTemplate’ in the course partial view

Comment: I fixed it. Please check now. Initially, I was passing Courses object to _editCourse partial view, but courses object was null when I submit, so I tried passing the teacher template since main view has TeacherTemplate as model but it is still the same result. Whenever I submit form courses object is null.

Comment: I’m on the phone so not 100% sure of this, but in the main edit, the @Html.Action you’re using for passing the model to the course edit action method is wrong. You cannot pass a whole model, because you’re basically passing an URL in the form of Action/Controller/Model, which is not possible as I recall. Instead, try passing the teacherTemplateId to that action method and build a new model from within that method, and be sure to set the correct MapRoute

Comment: I also had tried this : @Html.Partial("_editCourse", Model)  and it still didn't help.

Comment: The EditCourse method’s argument doesn’t have a type, is that a misspelling?

Comment: Yes, it was a misspelling. I fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure we aren't missing anything else? Please, paste actual code...

Comment: I have added all the code what I am doing. I am not actually supposed to post real classes so I have created another solution with the above details. Please see the changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering because comments aren't suitable for what I'm writing. I still suggest that changing the way you call your partial view is your best option:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Course", "EditCourse", new { Model.CurrentTeacherID })
```

This obviously requires that you change your action method in the TeacherTemplateController (not the same variables and arguments but you got the idea):

```
public ActionResult EditCourse(int teacherID)
{
    TeacherTemplate model = new TeacherTemplate(teacherID);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Please, note that this method requires that you create a `EditCourse` view.